# HashBytes function in SQL Server (wrong MD5 result)

Tags: sql-server, hash, md5

I faced on a strange problem with a SQL Server function `HashBytes`.

I have a column `Password` in my `Users` table (`nvarchar(32), not null`).

The user's password is `123456` which is `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` in MD5 and this value is stored in the column.

I am trying to get MD5 hash function of `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` which is actually `14e1b600b1fd579f47433b88e8d85291` (you may check it [here](http://www.md5.cz/)), however in my SQL Server query, I get a totally another result:

```
SELECT TOP 1
   Password,
   lower(convert(nvarchar(32), HashBytes('MD5', '123456'), 2)) AS md5pass1,
   lower(convert(nvarchar(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'), 2)) AS md5pass2,
   lower(convert(nvarchar(32), HashBytes('MD5',  Password), 2)) AS md5pass3
FROM Users
```

Result is:

[image]

and I expect to get '14e1b600b1fd579f47433b88e8d85291' as a result...

I appreciate you helping me!

Comment: "I am trying to get MD5 hash func of 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e' which is actually ..." erm why are you taking MD5 of a MD5? Also, why are you using MD5 at all?

Comment: Hi Mitch. I need this to generate a token. In my app actually the result md5 will consist of 3 columns (userid+ appid + password). I have checked that HashBytes(userid+appid) return correct md5 hash, hovewer only password md5 hash is wrong...

Comment: Why is this *wrong* ? What's your expectation?? MD5 is a **non-reversible** hash algorithm - applying MD5 hash on a MD5 hash value doesn't give you back the original password.....

Comment: I dont need to get the password back! I just want to get md5 hash of a string 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', nothing more

Comment: Marc, my expectation is to get md5 '14e1b600b1fd579f47433b88e8d85291' of a string 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'.

Comment: Question makes no sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: I have a string "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e", MD5 hash of this string is "14e1b600b1fd579f47433b88e8d85291", but in SQL using HashBytes I get "de9312fbbc167bc15fe988d9e3ddfc86". Why it is so?...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot hash text, you can only hash bytes. `HashBytes` converts the input string to bytes first. The conversion depends on whether the data type is a Unicode type. I guess that `Password` is `nvarchar` and I see that your literals are `varchar`.

Decide which one you want and use it consistently.

Comment: thank you! Did'nt know, you have helped me.
HashBytes('MD5',   convert(varchar(32), Password))

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that [nvarchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) you used is unicode. Get correct result once it converted to non-unicode varchar. Since it's password why not use varchar directly.